# angle sine and cosine identities problem 3

Tags: trigonometry

Write in terms no greater than one.

$$\sin^3x$$

I originally thought the answer was $\sin x\sin x\sin x$, I was wrong. After using these sine and cosine identities, I came up with

$$\frac{1}{8}(3-4\cos(2x)+\cos(4x))$$ Is this right?

Comment: I used the sine power-reducing identity, then the cosine power-reducing identity

Comment: One way  is to find $\sin(3x)=\sin(x+2x)=\sin x\cos 2x+\cos x\sin 2x$. We get $\sin x\cos 2x=\sin x(1-\sin^2 x)$ and $\cos x\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos^2 x=2\sin x(1-\sin^2 x)$.  Thus $\sin 3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3 x$, and now you can solve for $\sin^3 x$.

Comment: @user242559, was my answer helpful to you? If there is something which needs clarification I would be happy to improve the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to check if your identity is valid is to plot your result and what its is supposed to equal. Here is a plot of $y=\sin^(x)$ and $y=\frac18 (3\cos(x) - 4\cos(2x)+\cos(4x))$ from Wolfram Alpha.

[image]

Notice how the two graphs don't line up? This tells us that the proposed identity is wrong.

Based on what I think your instructions are (they seem kinda vague) I came up with the following,

$$ \sin^3(x) = \sin^2(x) \sin(x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2} \sin(x) = \frac{\sin(x) - \sin(x)\cos(2x)}{2} = \frac{\sin(x) - (\sin(2x+x) - \sin(2x-x))/2 }{2} = \frac{3sin(x)-\sin(3x) }{4}$$

The algebraic steps seem right, but we can check our reasoning by plotting my result and $sin^3(x)$.

[image]

The graphs line up suggesting that the answer is a valid identity.